# NSDate from NSString read from sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsstring, nsdate

I have the need of getting NSDate format from a `NSString *stringDate` and I would do that by using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

The above code works fine if I initialize my string manually `NSString *stringDate = @"2013-01-14 17:55:53";`, so I get the date in `NSDate` format correct.

But I am reading the string from an sqlite3 database, so the string is initialized as follows:

```
NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
```

The string is NSLogged correctly, but when I try to get the NSDate format i get only `(null)`.

Any ideas of what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What's the string you're getting from the database? Also, why are you casting the return value of `sqlite3_column_text()`?

Comment: The string I am getting from the db is `2012-12-19 21:48:27 +0000`. What should I use if not `sqlite3_column_text()`?

Comment: @userXXX you should use that function, but you should not cast its return value.

Comment: I will think about `sqlite3_column_text()`. Thanks for the help about the time zone marker!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you read from the sqlite is not in the format that you are using in dateformatter.

EDIT:

Use `formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z";` or trimming time zone `(+0000)` will solve your problem.-*By Inder Kr. Rathore*

Comment: The string I read from the db is `2012-12-19 21:48:27 +0000`. Why is it not in the right format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @user1862717 Because it ends with the time zone marker (`+0000`).

Comment: using `formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z";` or trimming time zone (+0000) will solve his problem. Please complete your answer based on his/her comments. Then I'll be happy to upvote :)

Comment: By the way, I was not using the time marker in the date format because I was not using it when writing in the db either. Don't know why it is appearing again.

Comment: This is ad added (unwanted but usefull) property of NSDate.